# How to implement the search for places included in a limited location on Google map in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have the coordinates stored in the Firebase database, from there I get all these coordinates, and I want to make it so that I can find out how many coordinates are included in the area bounded by my circle.Question: How do I implement the boundaries of this blue circle? (The circle is in the image).

Here is the image: [Google Maps][1]

Here is the code where I get all the coordinates from Firebase:

```
if (model.getPostId() != null) {
           if(model.getLat() != 0 && model.getLon() != 0){
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lat = " + model.getLat() + "Lon = " + model.getLon(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
}
```

Please help me! I have been looking for 5 days for information on how to do this, but I have not found it: (thank you in advance!

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeY8a.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeY8a.jpg!%5Benter) image description here]

Here is another example:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyoan.jpg)![enter image description here]

Here is another example:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHw7L.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the centre coordinates(,) of the circle and the radius (). Then get the distance of your firebase coordinates (,) from the centre of the circle. =√((−)2+(−)2). The point (,) is inside the circle if <, on the circle if =, and outside the circle if >.

So if you added the circle like this:

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
 .center(new LatLng(xc, yc))
 .radius(r)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Then you should have the centre coordinates and the radius to use this formula.

```
double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((xp-xc),2)+Math.pow((yp-yc),2));

if(d<r || d==r){
   //your logic in here
}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, yes, I know what this code that you gave me does, but I need something else, your code makes it so that a circle is created around a certain point, but this is not what I need at all. I have this blue circle (which is in the image) it will also move together when you move around the map. And your code creates a circle around a certain point, and when you move around the map, this circle will not move with me. This feature (which I need) seems to be called "Search Nearby"

Comment: I added two more pictures to my question to understand what I want to implement. I need to implement coverage

Comment: You're asking how to check if your firebase coordinates are within the circle. How the circle is drawn is irrelevant. My answer shows you how you can use the radius and center point of your circle to check what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks! I could do it!!  God bless you♥️